# Tomcat 10 migration with logback-logstash-encoder

Tags: java, tomcat10, logstash-logback-encoder

I'm using tomcat9 and migrate to tomcat10. I have migrate my application from javax.* to jakarta new servlet api to be compatible.

But when i'm starting tomcat 10, i'm getting this error :

```
16:31:38,422 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.ImplicitModelHandler - 
Assuming default type 
[net.logstash.logback.composite.loggingevent.StackTraceJsonProvider] for [stackTrace] property
16:31:38,611 |-ERROR in net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder@53c47a3f - Error occurred while dynamically loading jackson modules java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module: com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jdk8.Jdk8Module not a subtype
at java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module: com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jdk8.Jdk8Module not a subtype
at  at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:593)
...
...
```

I hava add logstash-logback-encoder 7.3 (last version) / logback-core;logback-classic 1.4.7 (last version)

I'm using jackson 2.15.1 (last version too)

I have another application that run in spring-boot 3 and all work fine with same version of components. So the problem is linked to tomcat10, but why?

I don't clearly understand this error if someone can help me.

If i put in comment my appender-ref in logback.xml, error disappear and application start correctly.

Thanks